# Angular JS $scope element undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to setup a directive but it appears Im having some trouble assigning something to $scope and using it somewhere else. I got this from this tutorial: http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

Here is my directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                console.log(scope);
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I printed out `scope` and I can see that the element is getting populated. But when I call it here:

```
myApp.controller('WizardController', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, fileUpload) {

$scope.submitForm = function () {

        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ');

        console.dir(file);
}

}]);
```

it returns $scope.myFile as undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is some additional code:

```
<form>
<input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
<button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: To help you solve your problem, others will need to verify that it *exists*. **Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!** If you inadvertently fixed the problem while composing the example but didn't test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to help.

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/i9XaG1Cgz0XOQtppgllW?p=preview).